# Kill actor if it times out in Spray app

Tags: scala, akka, spray

In my Spray app, I delegate requests to actors. I want to be able to kill a actor that takes too long. I'm not sure whether I should be using Spray timeouts, Akka ask pattern or something else.

I have implemented:

```
def processRouteRequest(system: ActorSystem) = {
  respondWithMediaType(`text/json`) {
    params { p => ctx =>
      val builder = newBuilderActor
      builder ! Request(p) // the builder calls `ctx.complete`
      builder ! PoisonPill
      system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(routeRequestMaxLife, builder, Kill)
    }
  }
}
```

The idea being that the actor lives only for the duration of a single request and if it doesn't complete within `routeRequestMaxLife` it gets forcibly killed. This approach seems over-the-top (and spews a lot of info about undelivered messages). I'm not even certain it works correctly.

It seems like what I'm trying to achieve should be a common use-case. How should I approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to using the ask pattern and handling the requests as follows:

```
class RequestHandler extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "quick" => 
      sender() ! "Quick Reply"
      self ! PoisonPill

    case "slow" =>
      val replyTo = sender()
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 seconds, self, replyTo)

    case a:ActorRef =>
      a ! "Slow Reply"
      self ! PoisonPill
  }
}

class ExampleService extends HttpService with Actor {
  implicit def actorRefFactory = context

  import context.dispatcher

  def handleRequest(mode: String):Future[String] = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(1 second)
    val requestHandler = context.actorOf(Props[RequestHandler])
    (requestHandler ? mode).mapTo[String]
  }

  val route: Route =
    path("endpoint" / Segment) { str =>
      get {
        onComplete(handleRequest(str)) {
          case Success(str) => complete(str)
          case Failure(ex) => complete(ex)
        }
    }
  }

  def receive = runRoute(route)
}
```

This way the actor takes care of stopping itself, and the semantics of Ask give you the information about whether or not the request timed out.